# How to merge gridview column vertically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview. That I want to merge vertically. I have uploaded my present output grid and ma expected output grid.Please take a look and help me.

My present output:

[image]

I want to make it as below grid

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`Header Template`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.headertemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it will allow you to create your header as you want.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <th rowspan="3">Sr NO.</th>
    <tr class="gvHeader">
      ...
    </tr>
```

Here is a good example

http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1077/gridview-multiple-header-rows

Answer (score 0):

As you didnt post any code snippet ,so on  `onrowcreated="grdViewProducts_RowCreated"` you can
 able to achieve the required o/p . Adding to shekar here is another good example  :

http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2010/12/how-to-create-multiple-row-header-and.html